# Sprite not displaying unless android app pauses - LibGDX

Tags: java, android, mobile, libgdx, 2d

Here is the code:
http://hastebin.com/ugufakeyap.java

When I run this, the sprite "aspectRatios" is not displayed on the screen. But when I pause the program by pressing my home button and then resuming the program, it displays the sprite onto the screen. Why is this? It's really annoying.

Comment: Any logcat output of value?

Comment: Nope, I don't see anything of value in there.

Comment: Does it work in the Desktop project?

Answer (score 0):

you need to call `camera.update();` after changing position. My best guess is that libGDX automatically updates the camera on resume.

```
public void create () {
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    txt = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("test2.png"));
    aspectRatios = new Sprite(txt);
    aspectRatios.setPosition(0,0);
    //aspectRatios.setSize(100,100);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    viewport = new StretchViewport(1080,1920,camera);

    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
    camera.update();
    viewport.apply();
    //batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
}
```

You would normally update the batch projection matrix there as well but you do it every frame in the render method anyway.

Comment: Have you tried moving the camera around? maybe comment out the camera.position.set line and see what you get. When the camera updates it centers the view on the viewport anyways. `projection.setToOrtho(zoom * -viewportWidth / 2, zoom * (viewportWidth / 2), zoom * -(viewportHeight / 2), zoom
   * viewportHeight / 2, near, far);` as is in `update()` in https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/OrthographicCamera.java

Comment: When I comment out update() and apply() i see a blank white thing on the screen, but not the sprite.

Comment: At least something changed. I'll have to wait until I get home to address this further.

Answer (score 0):

Some people helped me on the *libGDX irc channel*. 
It turns out that I wasn't calling

```
viewport.update(width, height, centerCamera);
```

(Thanks to **Xoppa**)

And (according to **ASneakyFox**):
"you have to assume that the android device isnt going to be conveniently the size you want, itll call resize when the app opens up or changes orientation so you can modify your layout to be the dimensions of the screen (ie change the viewport)"

Here is the updated version of the code:
http://hastebin.com/olivopocix.java

Comment: You can accept your own answer (and earn a funny badge by doing so).